# Debugger is returning this error

Tags: facebook, debugging

I have a problem..the Debugger is returning this error:

Errors That Must Be Fixed

More Than One OG URL Specified:

More Than One OG URL Specified  Object at URL 'http://www.health-alternative.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: http://www.health-alternative.com/, http://health-alternative.com/.

Could you tell me what it can be?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When called without the “www” prefix, `http://health-alternative.com/`, your site automatically redirects to the version *with* www, `http://www.health-alternative.com/`

But your meta tags say, the version without www is the correct one:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://health-alternative.com/">
```

So you should decide on one of the two options … right now, you are contradicting yourself in what the page actually does and what the meta tag says.